# Google Cloud Load Balancer pricing in standard tier

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to reduce my k8s GCP load balancing costs for CI/CD purposes, so looking for an explanation of pricing for a Load Balancer in the standard tier. I have read through

https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/overview

and

https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/pricing

but these documents determine pricing by egress $/GB.

From what I understood, a premium tier Load Balancer is priced according to number of configured routing rules. How would I get billed for Load Balancer in the standard tier?

Answer (score 2):

**Forwarding rules charges**

> ```
> First 5 forwarding rules                  $0.025  Per Hour
> Per additional forwarding rule            $0.010  Per Hour
> Ingress data processed by load balancer   $0.008  Per GB
> ```

1 - The Load balancing and forwarding table above contains the charge for ingress data processed by load balancers.

2 - Normal egress rates are charged for traffic outbound from a load balancer.

3 - There is no additional load balancer egress cost beyond normal egress rates.

Forwarding rules charges

Compute Engine charges for forwarding rules that are created for load balancing or other uses of forwarding rules.

**The following examples:**

Up to 5 forwarding rules you create are charged at $0.025/hour. For example, if you create one forwarding rule, you will be charged $0.025/hour. If you have 3 forwarding rules, you will still be charged $0.025/hour. However, if you have 10 rules, you will be charged:

5 forwarding rules = $0.025/hour

Each additional forwarding rule = $0.01/hour

$0.025/hour for 5 rules + (5 additional rules * $0.01/hour) = $0.075/hour

Comment: What is "per hour" in this case? The time it takes to forward the request, or the time the rule is active (always on => 24 hours per day * 30 days month), or something else?